# How to one data file upload into multiple table by sql loader in oracle 10g example

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

```
Create table emp (id varchar2(22), name varchar2(85),hire_date date,department_id varchar2(3));



create table emp_epfo as select id emp_id,name lname,hire_date,department_id dept_id from emp where 1=2;
```

Control file

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE   '/image/ExtTableData/OnlineClaims/member_master.csv'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE EMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
(ID ,NAME ,
HIRE_DATE ,DEPARTMENT_ID)
INTO TABLE EMP_EPFO
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(EMP_ID,LNAME,HIRE_DATE,DEPT_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single control file to load data into more than one tables using `SQLLDR`. What you need to keep in mind is,

```
 LOAD DATA
    INFILE   '/image/ExtTableData/OnlineClaims/member_master.csv'
    TRUNCATE
    INTO TABLE EMP
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (ID POSITION(1),
      NAME,
      HIRE_DATE,
      DEPARTMENT_ID
    )
    INTO TABLE EMP_EPFO
    (EMP_ID POSITION(1),
     LNAME,
     HIRE_DATE,
     DEPT_ID
     )
```

The reason for specifying `POSITION(1)` after the columns for separate tables is to instruct Oracle to start reading data from first row.

Quoting from Oracle documentation:

> When the POSITION parameter is not used, multiple INTO TABLE clauses
>   process different parts of the same (delimited data) input record,
>   allowing multiple tables to be loaded from one record. When the
>   POSITION parameter is used, multiple INTO TABLE clauses can process
>   the same record in different ways, allowing multiple formats to be
>   recognized in one input file.